# How to extract data of updated,inserted and deleted records from salesforce using REST api

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-lake

I have to extract the data which got inserted,deleted and updated from salesforce  using Rest Api or any other way. Can someone help me on this.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Logic Apps with the Salesforce connector in order to get the data and then, just use Azure Data Lake Connector to persist the data.

You can also do it using a programming language and consuming the Salesforce REST API directly:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_code.htm

Comment: Thanks thiago for your reply...i will get the data with salesforce connector but  i need to extract the data which got updated,deleted and inserted for that particular object using rest api using postman or logic apps

Comment: the API reference is in the link I've shared.

Comment: :i have tried using the saleforce doc but i'm getting could not get any response error in postman. I have used the following url
https://ax22.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Account/updated/​​​?start=2019-01-20T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end=2020-05-18T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00.
Can you please help me with this?